# Add a New If Statement within an Existing If Block

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that compares Columns A and B and adds 1 to column B if A is greater:

```
Sub test07()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 12 To LastRow

            If Range("A" & i).Value > Range("B" & i).Value Then

                Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value + 1

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

I would like to add the same thing again but with columns C and D, but I am getting syntax errors, ie:

```
Sub test07()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 12 To LastRow

            If Range("A" & i).Value > Range("B" & i).Value Then

                Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value + 1

            If Range("C" & i).Value > Range("D" & i).Value Then

                Range("D" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value + 1

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Many thanks

Comment: Add an End If before your new if statement.

Comment: That's working thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also become familiar with ElseIf - ElseIf is the same as doing an End If followed by a new If statement *except that* it only runs if the first If statement resulted in False. ie: assume A1 = 5, and you want to check A1's value to determine B1's value. You could check values in two ways:

**Option 1, using End If followed by a new If statement:**

```
If Range("A1") > 3 Then 
    B1 = 2
End If
If Range("A1") > 4 Then 
    B1 = 1
End If 'Because A1 = 5, both If statements are True, and therefore B1 will equal 1, because that is the last line of code which affects it
```

**Option 2, using ElseIf:**

```
If Range("A1") > 3 Then 
    B1 = 2
ElseIf Range("A1") > 4 Then 
    B1 = 1
End If 'Because A1 = 5, the first If statement is True, the ElseIf statement never runs, and therefore B1 will equal 2, because that is the only line of code which affects it.
```

Both methods are valid - you just need to understand the logic pathways that you are actually after to decide which you want to use.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, you are missing an `End If`. However, you are also not taking full advantage of the explicit parentage that comes with using the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to identify the worksheet.

```
Sub test07()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 12 To lastRow
            If .Range("A" & i).Value > .Range("B" & i).Value Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value + 1
            End If   '<~~might have to be three lines down depending upon how you want your logic to flow
            If .Range("C" & i).Value > .Range("D" & i).Value Then
                .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Note the use of `.Range` and `.Cells` ; not `Range` and `Cells`. The prefix period (aka *full stop*) associates the ranges and cells with the worksheet referenced in the `With ... End With`.

Getting back to the `If ... End If` issue, if you wish to avoid closing off the `If` statements, you **can** use them like the following.

```
Sub test07()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 12 To lastRow
            If .Range("A" & i).Value > .Range("B" & i).Value Then _
                .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value + 1
            If .Range("C" & i).Value > .Range("D" & i).Value Then _
                .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This method only works with a single relevant code line coming after the `If` code line.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply also copy/paste your code and modify the

```
Range("A" & i) --> Range("A" & i).Offset(#rows,#cols)
```

Or even better yet, ditch the "Range" and use "Cells" with two iterators and a nested FOR loop...

```
With...

for i in {#rowStart} To {#rowEnd}
    for j in {#colstart} To {#Colend}
        .Cells(i,j).Value = {put stuff here}
```

use the Ubound(Range()) to count elements in an array and size up your i & j, etc....